# How to display error messages on a page Angular 2

Tags: angular, error-handling, httpclient

I am trying to use http interceptor to add headers with the http request and it's working fine. Now I want to display the error messages on the page. So Is there any way to show error messages using the http interceptor? I have no idea how to show error messages on a page.

Sample:

InterceptorService:

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
     }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'x-auth-token': this.authService.getToken()
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling error with http global service angular 4.3, handleError , 401, 0, etc, interceptor , jwt, headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512701/handling-error-with-http-global-service-angular-4-3-handleerror-401-0-etc)

Comment: Yeah I have gone through it but how I will display those errors to different pages..